# Does "one-to-one" always refer to injective?

Tags: functions

Does one-to-one always refer to injective function or can it also refer to bijective or something else?

Comment: Some authors use it also for bijecton, but traditoonally one-to-one and onto is a bijection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quote from Wolfram Mathworld:  A map is called "one-to-one" (or "1:1") if it is injective. However, being in "one-to-one correspondence" is synonymous with being a bijection. Unfortunately, this confusing terminology is widely used throughout the literature.